# Can I set a sequence or combo of letter keys as my escape key in ratpoison?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, ratpoison

I have `inoremap jk <Esc>` in my vimrc, allowing me to escape by pressing two keys that are easy to reach but almost never pressed in sequence during normal typing.

I know that in .ratpoisonrc syntax you can do `escape Super_L` or eg `escape C-j` or even `escape j`.

I want to avoid having to reach around in weird places every time I escape. Just `escape j` would obviously be unusable if I ever want to type a 'j' within a window, so I need a sequence or a combo. I tried `escape j-k`, but it seems the `C-<letter>` syntax doesn't generalize, since that just resets it to `C-t`. `escape jk` and `escape j k` also reset it to `C-t`.

I am on Arch. Ratpoison is currently using X window server and xterm.

Is there a way to make ratpoison read [eg] either j-then-k, or j+k, as my escape key?